# Regular expression replace in PL/pgSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

If I have the following input (excluding quotes):

```
"The ancestral   territorial      imperatives of the    trumpeter swan"
```

How can I collapse all multiple spaces to a single space so that the input is transformed to:

```
"The ancestral territorial imperatives of the trumpeter swan"
```

This is going to be used in a trigger function on insert/update (which already trims leading/trailing spaces). Currently, it raises an exception if the input contains multiple adjacent spaces, but I would rather it simply transforms it into something valid before inserting.

What is the best approach? I can't seem to find a regular-expression replace function for PL/pgSQL. There is a `text_replace` function, but this will only collapse at most two spaces down to one (meaning three consecutive spaces will collapse to two). Calling this function over and over is not ideal.

Comment: For what version of Postgres?  `regexp_replace` is available 8.1+: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: NOOOooooooooooo! I'm stuck on 7.3.

Comment: I noticed your comment after I posted my answer.  Perhaps it's time to upgrade.  The ARE regex flavor in PosgreSQL 8 is far more powerful than the old POSIX flavors in previous versions of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) function that you should be able to use.

```
DECLARE
  result VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  result := REGEXP_REPLACE(subject, $$ {2,}$$, $$ $$, 'g');
END;
```

Comment: I'm just going to have to upgrade. This old version of PostgreSQL is beginning to reveal more and more reasons to use a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use plperl, and use perl regular expressions for the purpose.

Upgrading is good, but plperl can let you scrape by a little longer.